# Generate form based on fields defined in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I would like to generate rails form runtime based on the fields defined in database.

Current Structure of database

```
**fields table**
 - id
 - field_name
 - field_value
 - field_type (text field, date, dropdown)
 - field_values (Basically for list of values to be shown for dropdown field_type)
 - field_validation
```

Eg: If my database fields table stores following data

```
  1 | employee_name | text_field |  | {blank => false, :length => 3..50}
  2 | gender        | dropdown   | male, female | {blank => false}
```

Now based on above data I want to generate form as shown below

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@field, url: eval(url)) do |f|  %>
      <%= f.input_text :employee_name %>
      <%= f.collection :gender %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: go here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/ have a look

Comment: Thanks Phoet
I already searched ruby-toolbox.com for different options.

Comment: What phoet is pointing out is that "where is a gem that can do X" is usually considered off topic at Stack Overflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic item 5 in the "off topic" section. If you are lucky someone who knows the answer immediately and easily may comment to that effect. I'm sorry I do not - unless you simply mean "How do I write a form template that uses my field description data" in which case why not use `haml` or `erb`?

Comment: Thanks Neil.

I am specifically not interested in direct gem but some help on generating form based on field_type defined in database. How can I achieve it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: OK, that is clearer. It would help if you provided more details of what you have done so far. How about adding the following to the question (by editing in): 2 rows from database describing 2 form fields, a desired HTML form containing those fields, your Ruby code as it is where you attempt to create that form? Even if it is not complete, seeing what you have so far gives important context that helps other SO users to help you.

Comment: Sure. I will post database details in sometime.

Comment: Neil, I have updated my questions. Can you please look into it and give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `ActiveModel` for solving pretty much the same problem.

```
 # somewhere in metainfo model
def class_from_meta
  klass = Class.new do
    include ActiveModel::Model

    def self.name
      'Person'
    end
  end

  [:id, :email, :age].each do |attr|
    klass.instance_eval do
      attr_accessor attr
      validates_presence_of attr
    end
  end

  klass
end

# in controller
def create
  @person = MetaInfo.find(params[:meta_info_id]).class_from_meta.new
  respond_with @person
end
```

With `class_eval` and `instance_eval` you can generate a class which will behave prettly much like `ActiveRecord`

Comment: Thanks Synapse. Will try above solution and let you know

Comment: Thanks Synapse. Your solution worked for me.

I implemented with slightly different approach